# Bootstrap Modal + Morris.js Chart

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, morris.js

I'm having some problems getting a morris.js chart to show up in a bootstrap modal correctly. Not only is the sizing off but the chart doesn't draw. I have searched around and so far can't find a solution that works for me. Can anyone help?

**Edit**: Figured out the sizing issue, but it's still not drawing the graph. Thanks!

Modal Markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="clusterpulse" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="clusterpulse" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pulse</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>Versions by Environment</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
   <div id="morris-chart-versions"></div>

   </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
   </div><!-- /.panel-primary -->
   </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

JS:

```
<script>

        $(function () {

            // Create a Bar Chart with Morris
            var chart = Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris-chart-versions',
                data: [0, 0], // Set initial data (ideally you would provide an array of default data)
                xkey: 'd', // Set the key for X-axis
                ykeys: ['test1','test2','test3'], // Set the key for Y-axis
                labels: ['test1','test2','test3'], // Set the label when bar is rolled over
                resize: true
                stacked: true

            });

            // Fire off an AJAX request to load the data
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "../scripts/all_versions.php", // This is the URL to the API

            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    // When the response to the AJAX request comes back render the chart with new data
                    chart.setData(data);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    // If there is no communication between the server, show an error
                    alert("error occured");
                });
        });
</script>
```

This is what it ends up looking like:
[image: Modal+Chart]

**Edit**: I figured out the sizing issue. It was the 'col-lg-4' in my markup. Left it in there from another graph on the main page. Now it looks like this:
[image]

**Edit2**: And when I removed the 'resize: true' from the js.
[image]

Comment: I would venture to bet that you are getting a js error check your log see what the error shows

Comment: Only have 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.' which is known and unrelated.

Comment: Perhaps your includes. Maybe it can't see the .js correctly. And I think morris needs a Raphael.js to work?

Comment: Yup, that's all there. I'm populating other graphs on the same page successfully. I actually just removed the 'resize: true' from the js and I can see the labels are correct, which means it's getting the data just not drawing the graph.

Comment: I posted an example let me know if you have any questions. Clicking the check mark and upvoting always helps :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the js that ended up letting me put a graph in a modal and redraw when clicked.

```
<script>
$('#clusterpulse').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { //listen for user to open modal
    $(function () {
    $( "#morris-chart-versions" ).empty(); //clear chart so it doesn't create multiple if multiple clicks
        // Create a Bar Chart with Morris
        var chart = Morris.Bar({
            element: 'morris-chart-versions',
            data: [0, 0], // Set initial data (ideally you would provide an array of default data)
            xkey: 'd', // Set the key for X-axis
            ykeys: ['test1','test2','test3'], // Set the key for Y-axis
            labels: ['test1','test2','test3'], // Set the label when bar is rolled over
            stacked: true
        });

        // Fire off an AJAX request to load the data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "../scripts/all_versions.php", // This is the URL to the API

        })
            .done(function (data) {
                // When the response to the AJAX request comes back render the chart with new data
                chart.setData(data);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                // If there is no communication between the server, show an error
                alert("error occured");
           });
        });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I see your problem. Its how you are formating your data the charts can't understand it.

Here is an example of something I have used:

```
  var data = [];
  var mult = 200;
  for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
             data.push({y: 1300+(i*mult), value: 30*i});
  }
```

This is my parameters for the chart

```
  Morris.Line({
       // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
       element: 'linechart',
       // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
       // the chart.
       data: data,
       // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
       xkey: 'y',
       // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
       ykeys: ['value'],
       // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
       // chart.
       labels: ['y'],
       // Disables line smoothing
       smooth: false,
           parseTime: false,
     });
```

What I did for redraw on tabs because redraw didnt seem to work:

```
   $('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
    // this ain't pretty, but you should get the idea
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#AMD' && $('#line2').html().length == 0) {
     Morris.Area({       
       element: 'line2',
       data: chartdata,    
       xkey: 'd',
       ykeys: ['visits'],
       labels: ['USD'],
       // Disables line smoothing
       smooth: false,
     });
        $(document).scrollTop( $("#myTab").offset().top );
    }
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#TTWO' && $('#line3').html().length == 0) {
     Morris.Area({
       element: 'line3', 
       data: data,
       xkey: 'd',
       ykeys: ['visits'],
       labels: ['USD'],
       smooth: false,
     });
        $(document).scrollTop( $("#myTab").offset().top );
    }
});
```

This is an old version of the code but you should get the idea.
The key part here is:

```
    $('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
       if ($(e.target).attr('href') ==
```

which I think can be applied to modals

Comment: I use this same chart on another page without problems. I think the problem is something with the modal needed to redraw the chart when it's opened but I can't figure out how to redraw. Tried something like this: $('#clusterpulse').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    alert("shown");
    chart.redraw();
   });

Comment: Oh, and if the keys were incorrect it wouldn't show data in the label correct?

Comment: Oh yes redraw! I have had the same problem with tabs and morris charts. Ill update my post to show What I did. You can or "try" to apply it to modals

Comment: Thank you. The redraw() wasn't working for me either but your code help me to fix it. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. actually I used a event 'shown.bs.modal' and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

you can delay the drawing of the graph.Following method gave me solution.

```
setTimeout( function(){
     Morris.Area({...})
  },1200);
```

you can change `1200` according to your graph and data set.